# Why doesn't **sort** sort the same on every machine?

Tags: bash, unix, sorting, ksh

Using the same **sort** command with the same input produces different results on different machines.  How do I fix that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [man-page](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sort.1.html) on OS X says:

> *******  WARNING ******* The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get
> the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

which might explain things.

If some of your systems have no locale support, they would default to that locale (C), so you wouldn't have to set it on those. If you have some that supports locales and want the same behavior, set `LC_ALL=C` on those systems. That would be the way to have as many systems as I know do it the same way.

If you don't have any locale-less systems, just making sure they share locale would probably be enough.

For more canonical information, see The Single UNIX ® Specification, Version 2 description of [locale](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/locale.html), [environment variables](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/envvar.html), [setlocale()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/setlocale.html) and the description of the [sort(1)](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/sort.html) utility.

Comment: How does one set the locale to LC_ALL=C ?

Comment: @Malcolm : many recommendations will tell you to export the LC_ALL variable...but that clobbers the users shell settings. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923464/unix-sort-ignores-whitespaces/17180962#17180962) to set it for a set scope

Answer (score 5):

This can be the result of locale differences:

```
$ echo 'CO2_
CO_' | env LC_ALL=C sort
CO2_
CO_


$ echo 'CO2_
CO_' | env LC_ALL=en_US sort
CO_
CO2_
```

Setting the LC_ALL environment variable to the same value should correct the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to different settings of the [locale environment variables](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.nls/doc/nlsgdrf/locale_env.htm). `sort` will use these settings to determine how to compare strings. By setting these environment variables the way you want before calling `sort`, you should be able to force it to behave in one specific way.

Answer (score 3):

For more than you ever wanted to know about `sort`, read the [specification of `sort`](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sort.html) in the [Single Unix Specification v3](http://OpenGroup.Org/onlinepubs/009695399/). It states

> Comparisons [...] shall be performed using the collating sequence of the current locale.

IOW, how `sort` sorts is dependent on the locale (language) settings of the environment that the script is running under.