# How to sort lowercase to uppercase

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

How to sort lowercase to uppercase

For example

```
Dir3 dir1 dir2 dir3
```

In my case

```
Dir3 dir1 dir2 dir3

sort -f
dir1 dir2 Dir3 dir3
```

But I want

```
dir1 dir2 dir3 Dir3
```

How to sort lowercase to uppercase?

Comment: Try `LANG=en_US.utf8 sort -f ...`. The locale has an influence on the sort order. `en_US.utf8` will give you the desired results

Comment: `ls | env LC_ALL=en_US sort -f` and `ls | env LC_ALL= sort -f` gives different results for me, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881/why-doesnt-sort-sort-the-same-on-every-machine

Comment: I tried 2 cases and see the question, but, results are same....

Comment: what command are you sorting ? ls ? dir ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should solve your problem:

```
$ echo -e "Dir3\ndir1\ndir2\ndir3" | sort
dir1
dir2
dir3
Dir3
```